# eval-str in ClojureScript with public structure as a parameter

Tags: clojurescript

My problem requires applying custom logical functions to a structure. Those functions are stored in a database as a string. I have data like this:

```
(def fruits {:apple {:color "red" :ripe? true}
             :strawberry {:color "red" :ripe? false}})
```

And I have this cond check:

```
"(some (fn [fruit] (-> fruit val :ripe? false?)) fruits)"
```

Unfortunatelly I can't get this right even though I tried various approaches:

1)

```
(cljs/eval-str (cljs/empty-state)
           "(some (fn [fruit] (-> fruit val :ripe? false?)) my.main/fruits)"
           ""
           {:eval cljs/js-eval}
           identity)
```

This works yet it yields errors:

```
WARNING: No such namespace: my.main, could not locate my/main.cljs, my/main.cljc, or Closure namespace "" at line 1
WARNING: Use of undeclared Var my.main/fruits at line 1
```

Also this approach obviously wouldn't work in advanced compilation.

2) I tried to leverage approach that works in Clojure:

```
((eval
   (read-string
     "(fn [fruits]
       (some (fn [fruit] (-> fruit val :ripe? false?)) fruits))"))
  fruits)
```

I can't see why this wouldn't work in advanced compilation. Unfortunatelly it simply returns `nil` every single time.

Is it just me who fails to come up with a solution or is CLJS just not capable of doing that yet?

Comment: So it works for :simple and :whitespace? Perhaps reading in this direction will help: http://www.lispcast.com/clojurescript-externs

Comment: Sort of... First it says that `fruits` are not declared but then it calculates the result alright. I don't really understand why.

Comment: You might have to study up on externs and export, and also consider joining the cljs slack group and ask there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of experiments and struggling with evaluating functions from strings I decided to write DSL.

In database I store string with a map containing these parameters:

- :where? - vector containing path to a desired answer.
- :what? - answer(s) I'm looking for.
- :strict? (optional) - A boolean. If true then answers need to be exactly the same as `:what?` rule (order doesn’t matter).

Then I just evaluate that simple cljs file. It works both on `advanced` and `none` optimization mode.

```
(defn standard-cond-met? [{:keys [what? where? strict?]
                           :or {strict? false}}]
  (let [answer (get-in answers (conj where? :values))]
    (if strict?
      (= (sort what?) (sort answer))
      (clojure.set/subset?
        (set what?)
        (set answer)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your going to have a vary hard time achieving your requirement using
this approach. The big problem is likely going to be due to the way
clojurescirpt needs to be compiled into javascript (using Google closure). You
can probably get it to work doing some clever stuff with externals and using low
level javascript interop and the closure library, but I suspect it will be hard
work.

A couple of alternative approaches which may be worth considering

- Store the data in the database in edn format. Using edn, you may be able to
  read it into a var and then execute it
- Change direction - do you really need to store complete functions or could you
  instead define a type of DSL which obtains parameters from the database which
  will provide the necessary level of dynamic execution.
- Could you have some sort of pre-processing solution i.e. write the function in
  clojurescript, but use closure functionality to compile that to javascript and
  insert that into the database instead of the raw clojurescript. This would
  make the initial storing of the data more complex, but may simplify calling
  the dynamic functions at runtime. You could even include some code checks or
  validation to reduce the likelihood of code taken from the database doing the
  wrong thing.

There are so many risks associated with using totally dynamic code it is almost
never a good solution. Aside from the numerous security issues you have with
this approach, you also have to deal with elegantly handling problems arising
from buggy definitions being inserted into the database (i.e. a buggy function
definition which crashes your app or corrupts data. If you just have to have the
ability to dynamically execute unknown code, then at least edn provides some
additional protection you don't get with eval-str - but really, just don't do
it.